# Ghost not receiving any traffic

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, ghost-blog

I have Ghost running on nginx in an EC2 ubuntu instance. I am able to run the application and `curl` it from the instance it's in.

However, I cannot access it from the internet, or outside the instance. I checked my EC2 security groups and port 2368 (the port ghost uses) is open. Nginx is simply configured like so:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name server.name.io;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://54.xxx.xxx.xxx:2368;
  }

}
```

Where else should I look at?

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your your EC2 security group allows port 2368 but can you be more specific what is being allowed?  Inbound? Outbound? From what sources?

Also in your case because you are using Nginx to proxy requests to Ghost you will actually want to open port 80 on your security group and not 2368.  This way everybody will be forced to use port 80 and you will get the full benefits of Nginx.

You will want to make your security look like this:

- Allow traffic on port 80 from everywhere on the internet
- Allow traffic on port 22 from everywhere (if you are lucky to have a static IP at home you could change this to be more secure)
- Allow all outbound traffic to anywhere on the internet

[image]

[image]